# AWS Amplify with MySQL configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync-ios, amplify-ios

I already created an appsync API, which is connected to my MySQL database. In the AppSync Portal i can create and do querys and mutations. Now it comes to the step where i want to connect that API to Amplify - every documentation i read can't explain to me how i configure an existing resource in Amplify. And further, how i configure and use it in Code. In the first step i want to use it in Swift.

I already did an Amplify project in Swift, but without MySQL.

Steps i already did - install AWS CDK, generate graphql.sql.schema from database export. Create Swift project and init Amplify in the project folder.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not fully understand your question! It seems you have an API that connects to mysql and you want to use that API with amplify. If this is the case, then what does this question have to do with mysql? The mysql connection is handled by the API.

Comment: @Shadow yeah exactly. MySql does not primarily have to do with the question, but because Amplify normally doesn't use MySql, i thought it would be worth to mention that there is a special case of use Amplify. So the questions are:  How do i configure Amplify with the API and don't make a new Amplify Database? How do i configure Amplify in Swift? And how do i use the API Framework in Swift to speak with the right backend API? And how do i use the Framework for CRUD Operations in this particular case?

Comment: But amplify does not use mysql in your case either - it uses an API that uses mysql.